# Trying to use final variable in anonymous class. But its not passing the value. I'm unable to understand whats my mistake

Tags: java, closures, java-8

I'm using SWT package for creating GUI in java. I'm trying to print the same two Strings at two places. I defined them as final already. Still in the first case, its printing correctly. but in the inner method its just printing null. Please correct me where I'm doing wrong.

```
protected void createContents() {
final String inputFile = input.getText(); // input is  Textbox 
final String outputFile = output.getText(); // output is Textbox

System.out.println(inputFile);
System.out.println(outputFile);

btnStartConversion.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            //call conversion.
            try {
                System.out.println(inputFile);
                System.out.println(outputFile);
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                Convert convert = new Convert(inputFile,outputFile);
            } catch (IOException | JSONException | InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: In the second instance you have the prints occuring in a different class maybe this is the issue you are having

Comment: @user2693587 then what is the way to use them as closures. more over My requirement is to pass those Strings to the constuctor Convert upon pressing the btnStartConversion.

Please let me know if there is any better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using Java 8 Closures (Lambda).  You are using an anonymous class.  You probably need to reference `input` and `output` fields directly.

Assuming your outer class is named `OuterClass` (change as appropriate)

```
btnStartConversion.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        //call conversion.
        try {
            System.out.println(OuterClass.this.inputFile.getText());
            System.out.println(OuterClass.this.outputFile.getText());
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            Convert convert = new Convert(OuterClass.this.inputFile.getText(),
                                          OuterClass.this.outputFile.getText());
        } catch (IOException | JSONException | InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

(taken from my comment below)

I think the issue was this anonymous class handles Button events and needed to get the current values from some text boxes. By getting the values at object creation time, their values were of course blank or null. So by directly referencing the fields in the Listener you could get the current values every time the button is clicked.

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem. I'm new to this thing. This has cleared my concepts about anonymous classes too.

Comment: How does that make a difference? Wouldn't the local variables populated before they are copied to the local class instance variables?

Comment: @Rohit Jain: yeah, that’s quite confusing. In the question, `inputFile` and `outputFile` are local variables and have the type `String`, therefore can’t have a `getText()` method. If this answer solves the problem, there have to be *additional variables* not shown in the question and dkatzel was able to read the questioner’s mind, somehow. It’s also still not clear what was causing the problem as in the question’s code, there is no ambiguity regarding the variables.

Comment: I think part of the issue was this anonymous class handles Button events and needed to get the *current* values from some text boxes.  By getting the values *at object creation time* their values were of course blank or null.  So by directly referencing the fields in the Listener you could get the current values every time the button is clicked.

Comment: If `OuterClass.this.inputFile.getText()` worked, then `inputFile.getText()` would also work (unless somehow there is a local variable `inputFile` that shadows it), because inner classes already implicitly have access to the members of the outer class.

Comment: @newacct in the OP. `inputFile` would not have had any text yet at construction time if it was a user populated input. And even if it did, the listener would only have the original value, not any future updates

Comment: @dkatzel: I'm talking about in your code. There is no reason to need to use `OuterClass.this`

Comment: @RohitJain actually its a text box. To reduce unnecessary code part, I straight away mentioned it in comment. and he got it very cleverly. Accordingly I just picked up right variable of text box rather string. Ultimately i could able to read from text box and pass it as a string. thanks everybody.

Comment: @newacct Theoretically I too Inferred that and tried to maintain variable names different though they carry same data. Trust me, referencing that OuterClass.this worked like a charm (Though I don't know what made it to work).